# Error while updating sqlite row in ios

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I'm getting "error while updating row" error when I'm trying to update sqlite row in iOS. Here is my update method:

```
-(BOOL) updateResultForLesson:(int)lessonId result:(int)result{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update lessons set result=%d where id=%d",result, lessonId];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);


        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"updated");
        return YES;
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
            NSLog(@"error while updating row");
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return NO;

}
```

and here insert method which works fine:

```
-(BOOL) addLesson:(NSString *)title levelId:(NSInteger)levelId categoryId:(NSInteger)categoryId{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int result = 0;

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into lessons (title, level_id, category_id, result) values(\"%@\", \"%d\", \"%d\", \"%d\")",title, levelId, categoryId, result];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
           ;
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return NO;

}
```

what am I doing wrong? can anyone help? Insert and select methods works well, I have only problem with updating rows.

Comment: why u use multiple queries , try Insert or Replace Query  --> it is used for insert, update and delete function also.

Comment: ok, i tried NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert or replace into lessons (result) values(\"%d\") where id=\"%d\"",result, lessonId]; query but it didnt work neither :(

Comment: please updated your ?

Comment: sorry? what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use sqlite3_bind_ functions:

```
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const void*, int n, void(*)(void*));
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_double(sqlite3_stmt*, int, double);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_int(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_int64(sqlite3_stmt*, int, sqlite3_int64);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_null(sqlite3_stmt*, int);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const char*, int n, void(*)(void*));
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_text16(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const void*, int, void(*)(void*));
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_value(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const sqlite3_value*);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_zeroblob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int n);
```

and check if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` returns 'OK' result.

Try this code:

```
-(BOOL) updateResultForLesson:(int)lessonId result:(int)result{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
     BOOL success = NO;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        const char *query_stmt = "update lessons set result= ? where id= ? ";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
        {

            int bindRes = 0;
            bindRes = sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 0, result);
            bindRes = sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, lessonId);


            int state = sqlite3_step(statement);
            if (state == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                success = YES;
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to update record");
                success = NO;
            }
        }


        sqlite3_reset(statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        return success;
}
```

**WARNING:** 
I do not know the type of 'result', so you must use correct bind function for statement from the list

Comment: unfortunately doesnt work neither :( The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)

Comment: on which line exactly? cocoa error 260 - seems like your have troubles with your database path

Comment: I put dbpath into NSLog and that is what I got: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<xxxxxxx>/Documents/abc.db  - I replaced some numbers with "xxxx" cos maybe I shouldnt share this number :) i dont know :)

Comment: Could you set breakpoints and tell me, on which line you got those error?

Comment: i get this error after 'Failed to update record', it seems like maybe i dont have permission to update database records? cos i can insert, i can select..

Comment: ok, sure but anyway "failed to update record" appers before,ok, give me a minute

Comment: did you change bindRes = sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, result); for what you need ?

Comment: yep, i changed it for "sqlite3_bind_int"

Comment: change indexes from 1,2 to 0,1 as second param of sqlite3_bind_

Comment: i have no idea what can cause it... i'm thinking to add new table results where i will be inserting data and after selecting max since update doesnt want to work....

Comment: set two breakpoints on bindRes = sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 0, result);
            bindRes = sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, lessonId); and check bindRes variable. it should be 0 if bind was successful. if you get other code- read SQLite codes description and  try to understand why.

Comment: bind was successfull, equals 0, the problem is here " if (state == SQLITE_DONE)" , it returns false

Comment: ok, i found out interesting thing, i can invoke that method succesfully from one view controller and from the other not, so at least it works, i have to find out why it doesnt work in second view controller

Comment: if it helped you, you can mark post as answer, if you want, and ask another question - about your situation from different controllers

Answer (score 0):

Change your update query, you missed quote for value in query

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update lessons set result=\"%d\" where id=\"%d\"",result, lessonId];
```

Comment: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)"

and 

"error while updating row"

Comment: try to set  `sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;` and check your DB path with NSLog in your update function